# New customer email confimation goes to my email instead of the customers email address

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend

I just want to swap out the **customers email** to `example@mail.com` so I receieve the **confirmation code** so I can confirm accounts **before they are able to order**.

I am looking around in the **CreatePost.php** but can't see anywhere I can easily swap them out.

Thank you.